# <xsl:attribute> Performance

Tags: c#, performance, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a piece of XSL that just outputs an `<img>` and its source.

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="utils:Replace(@uri, '\', '/')" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

My utility is very simple:

```
public string Replace(string original, string oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            return original.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
        }
```

However when this runs with load I see memory and server cpu spikes.

If I just output the img src like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="utils:Replace(@uri, '\', '/')" />
```

No spikes.

Any clues as to why this is the case, a little baffled.

Comment: Can you try this against it? `<xsl:attribute name="src" select="utils:Replace(@uri, '\', '/')" />`

Comment: that would cause an error, using xslt 1.0 for reference. Select is an invalid attribute of attribute

Comment: How about trying this: `<img src="{utils:Replace(@uri, '\', '/')}" />`? Actually, if you are just replacing a single character with a single character, why not try using translate? `<img src="{translate(@uri, '\', '/')}" />`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but even that has caused a spike, very bizarre!

Comment: Asking about performance without saying what XSLT processor you are using seems a little strange. I guess since you've tagged it C# and you've said it's XSLT 1.0 that you're using the Microsoft processor?

Comment: Is the extension function written inline using `msxsl:script` or are you providing it as an extension object?